# on weak convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a sequence of cumulative distribution functions $F_n$ on $[0,\infty)$. Assume $F_n$ converge to some cdf $F$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $(X^{(n)}_1,\cdots,X^{(n)}_n)$ be i.i.d. sampled from $F_n$, and the empirical measure be defined as $\mathbb{P}_n={1 \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X^{(n)}_i}$. Assume independence for different $n$'s. Let $P$ be the probability measure corresponding to $F$. Then can we deduce $\mathbb{P}_n$ converges weakly to $P$?